# Multiple sorting query params with Backbone.paginator

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-paginator

I have followed a [tutorial](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/in-place-pagination-using-backbone-js-laravel-shop-tutorial) ([source code](https://github.com/msurguy/laravel-backbone-pagination)) and everything works great but I have one issue, **the sorting works but how do I add another sorting option?**

For example I have this

```
server_api: {
    'per_page': function() { return this.perPage },
    'page': function() { return this.currentPage },
    'year': function() {
        if (this.sortField === undefined)
            return '2016';
        return this.sortField;
    }
},
```

So I can sort my API using year, but my API can also accept another parameter like `sort_by`.

So I added this under year:

```
'sort_by': function() {
    if(this.sortField === undefined)
        return 'title.desc';
    return this.sortField;
}
```

Now every time I click the 'year button', it sorts based on year example:

```
sort_by=title.desc&year=2016

sort_by=title.desc&year=2011
```

but if click on `sort_by` button, it's changing the value of `year`, instead of `sort_by` example:

```
sort_by=title.desc&year=popularity.asc
```

My full code:

```
<script type="text/html" id="sortingTemplate">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Year <strong><span id="sortByYear">2016</span></strong> <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="year">
                <li><a href="2016">2016</a></li>
                <li><a href="2015">2015</a></li>
                <li><a href="2014">2014</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Sort by <strong><span id="sortBy">2016</span></strong> <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="sort_by">
                <li><a href="popularity.desc">Popularity Descending</a></li>
                <li><a href="popularity.asc">Popularity Ascending</a></li>
                <li><a href="vote_average.desc">Rating Descending</a></li>
                <li><a href="vote_average.asc">Rating Ascending</a></li>
                <li><a href="primary_release_date.desc">Release Date Descending</a></li>
                <li><a href="primary_release_date.asc">Release Date Ascending</a></li>
                <li><a href="title.asc">Title (A-Z)</a></li>
                <li><a href="title.desc">Title (Z-A)</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>

<script>



window.myapp = {};
    myapp.collections = {};
    myapp.models = {};
    myapp.views = {};
    myapp.serverURL = '{{url("/")}}';
    myapp.models.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    myapp.collections.PaginatedCollection = Backbone.Paginator.requestPager.extend({
      model: myapp.models.Item,
      paginator_core: {
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '{{ route('api.discover.movie') }}'
      },

      paginator_ui: {
        firstPage: 1,
        currentPage: 1,
        perPage: 20,
        totalPages: 10
      },

      server_api: {
        'per_page': function() { return this.perPage },
        'page': function() { return this.currentPage },
        'year': function() {
            if(this.sortField === undefined)
                return '2016';
            return this.sortField;
        },
        'sort_by': function(){
            if (this.sortField2 === undefined)
                return 'title.desc';
            return this.sortField2;
        }
      },
      parse: function (response) {
        $('#movies-area').spin(false);
        this.totalRecords = response.total;
        this.totalPages = Math.ceil(response.total / this.perPage);
        return response.data;
      }
    });
    myapp.views.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'div',
      className: 'col-lg-2',
      template: _.template($('#MovieItemTemplate').html()),
      initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('remove', this.remove, this);
      },
      render : function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
      }
    });
    myapp.views.SortedView = Backbone.View.extend({
      events: {
        'click #year a': 'updateYear',
        'click #sort_by': 'updateSortBy'
      },
      template: _.template($('#sortingTemplate').html()),
      initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
        this.$el.appendTo('#discover');
      },
      render: function () {
        var html = this.template(this.collection.info());
        this.$el.html(html);
        if (this.collection.sortField == undefined){
          var sortYearText = this.$el.find('#sortByYear').text();
        }else{
          var sortYearText = this.collection.sortField;
        }
        $('#sortByYear').text(sortYearText);

        if (this.collection.sortField2 == undefined){
          var sortByText = this.$el.find('#sortBy').text();
        }else{
          var sortByText = this.collection.sortField2;
        }
        $('#sortBy').text(sortByText);
      },
      updateYear: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentYear = $(e.target).attr('href');
        this.collection.updateOrder(currentYear);
        $('#movies-area').spin();
      },
      updateSortBy: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentSort = $(e.target).attr('href');
        this.collection.updateOrder(currentSort);
        $('#movies-area').spin();
      }
    });
    myapp.views.PaginatedView = Backbone.View.extend({
      events: {
        'click button.prev': 'gotoPrev',
        'click button.next': 'gotoNext',
        'click a.page': 'gotoPage'
      },
      template: _.template($('#paginationTemplate').html()),
      initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
        this.$el.appendTo('#pagination');
      },
      render: function () {
        var html = this.template(this.collection.info());
        this.$el.html(html);
      },
      gotoPrev: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#movies-area').spin();
        this.collection.requestPreviousPage();
      },
      gotoNext: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#movies-area').spin();
        this.collection.requestNextPage();
      },
      gotoPage: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#movies-area').spin();
        var page = $(e.target).text();
        this.collection.goTo(page);
      }
    });
    myapp.views.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el : '#paginated-content',
      initialize : function () {
        $('#movies-area').spin();
        var items = this.collection;
        items.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        items.on('all', this.render, this);
        items.pager();
      },
      addOne : function ( item ) {
        var view = new myapp.views.ItemView({model:item});
        $('#paginated-content').append(view.render().el);
      }
    });
    $(function(){
        myapp.collections.paginatedItems = new myapp.collections.PaginatedCollection();
        myapp.views.app = new myapp.views.AppView({collection: myapp.collections.paginatedItems});
        myapp.views.pagination = new myapp.views.PaginatedView({collection:myapp.collections.paginatedItems});
        myapp.views.sorting = new myapp.views.SortedView({collection:myapp.collections.paginatedItems});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are using a deprecated version of [backbone.paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator). There's a version 2 since 2014.

Comment: @EmileBergeron i know, i tried to use the newest version but then my app breaks and is hard to migrate for me as i am new in backbone

Comment: If it's the full code of your app, it would be easy to migrate as you only have one collection.

Comment: @EmileBergeron yes the the only code, but i will try it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quickfix

Change the values directly in the view's events callbacks:

```
updateYear: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentYear = $(e.target).attr('href');
    this.collection.sortField = currentYear;
    $('#movies-area').spin();
},
updateSortBy: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentSort = $(e.target).attr('href');
    this.collection.sortField2 = currentSort;
    $('#movies-area').spin();
}
```

## Better way

Name things with what they represent and encapsulate the logic.

In the collection, offer clearly named setters.

```
server_api: {
    /* ...snip... */
    'year': function() {
        return this.year || '2016';
    },
    'sort_by': function() {
        return this.sortField || 'title.desc';
    }
},

setYearFilter: function(value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
        this.year = value;
        return this.pager(options);
    }
    return reject();
},
```

And use them in the view:

```
updateYear: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentYear = $(e.target).attr('href');
    this.collection.setYearFilter(currentYear)
    $('#movies-area').spin();
},
updateSortBy: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentSort = $(e.target).attr('href');
    this.collection.updateOrder(currentSort);
    $('#movies-area').spin();
}
```

## Best way

Update to the latest version of [backbone.paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator), not that it will solve the problem directly, but it'll be easier to find help and documentation. Also, additional features!